# Unable to execute web3.eth.accounts[0]

Tags: solidity, testrpc, error, cors

I'm following along with [this short tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-(Tutorial)) and ran into a few problems. I'm running testrpc in my console. However, every time I run my index.html I get an error. My index.html file is the following:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>



    <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <h1>Coursetro Instructor</h1>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            } else {
                 // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
                 web3 = new Web3(newWeb3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
             }
             web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I get the 2 errors in the console: `Failed to load http://localhost:8545/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

and `Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:8545.`

both occur only when I try to execute `web3.eth.accounts[0]`.

The weirdest part about all of this is the fact that this was running fine last night. However, after closing chrome, I opened this up again and I had this error. Anybody know what to do?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpcapi "web3,eth" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcvhosts "*"
```

Go(https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#go)

You can start the HTTP JSON-RPC with the --rpc flag

geth --rpc

If accessing the RPC from a browser, CORS will need to be enabled with the appropriate domain set. 
Otherwise, JavaScript calls are limit by the same-origin policy and requests will fail:

geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:3000"

Comment: Hi, I'm struggling with this issue. Here are my steps:
1. use Ganache console to start a local blockchain. "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
2. truffle compile --network my_ganache
3. truffle migrate --network my_ganache
4. truffle console --network my_ganache
I can successfully call like 'web3.eth.account[0]' by far. But then I use "npm run dev" to start the server and I get the same problem: "Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.", "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7545/ due to access control checks.".. 

How can I do to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is easily solved by installing this version of web3:

```
npm install web3@0.20.6 --save
```

Courtesy to [Bereket-gebredingle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8954773/bereket-gebredingle)

Answer (score 0):

`npm install web3@0.20.6 --save`

That's good working